# Is there a lua equivalent of javascript's apply()?

Tags: javascript, lua

In Lua, is there an equivalent of Javascript's apply() function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using `()` and `unpack`

```
function sayhello(name, message)
    print("hello " .. name .. ". " .. message)
end

func1 = sayhello
args1 = {"test", "how are you"}
func1(unpack(args1))
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was the behavior I was looking for.